# Using EJB or Inject in a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a SOAP WebService class that has an EJB injected and some other class injected in it. Like:

```
public class SuperWS {

    @EJB
    private SuperDaoEjb superDaoEjb;

    @Inject
    private Partner partnerComponent;

    //......

    public Response invoke(Request req) {

        //Some logic

        Thread t = new Thread(new SuperRunnable(superDaoEjb, partnerComponent));

        t.start();

        return req;

    }

}
```

I have to do some logic then return the response but start a thread to process some more. In that thread I need both superEjbDao and partnerComponent. But as I know those objects are container managed. So I can't really say that container won't give the proxy to someone else or dispose it. I feel like there is a problem with my design. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Launching your own thread within a container (if you are running in a container) is discouraged, especially if you are interacting with EJB. Have you already considered the use of `@Asynchronous` or `@MessageDriven` ?

Comment: Yes, I considered using of @Asynchronous. I was afraid it will bring a little bit overhead and also I'll need one EJB for each asynchronous task.  Also I am aware of MDB and it's a little hard to use to my mind - you should create a lot of resources and maintain it. I think i will use the first one.

Comment: You can have as many @Asynchronous methods as you want within the same EJB.

Comment: But if I pass the injected value of SuperWS to asynchronous method of EJB won't it be the problem? Since the container can inject that instance to another WS or else. What kind problems can occur there?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no problem. It is essential design. Just be sure that both SuperDaoEjb and Partner have thread-safe code and you'll be fine. You do need to care about what reference you will get from Container for SuperDaoEjb and Partner.